# oracle, adding a new line to a nested table

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

I have these three object

```
create or replace 
type type_client 
( num int , 
  username varchar(30), 
  balance int, 
  ta table_achat, 
  ref_admin ref type_admin,
  member function get_prix_achat_total return int );



create or replace 
type table_achat as table of achat ;


create or replace 
type achat as object ( num_item int , qte int
);

create table table_client OF type_client ;
```

suppose in an entry of table_client .. we have a nested table like this :

```
(num_item,qte) : (1 , 5),(2 , 3)
```

what I want is the nested table be like this (for example):

```
(num_item,qte) : (1 , 5),(2 , 3)(3 , 44)
```

What I mean is, how to add a new line to an already created nested table while keeping existing entries?    ..

Comment: Could you show the definition of table_client?

Comment: @user9152856 : You should never post your question with whole sentences(especially while asking something) in UPPER CASE. It is generally used to express loudness ( or shouting )  in the internet and annoys people if you do it,  regardless of your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the MULTISET UNION operator to create a new set from two sets. In your case one of those sets is your existing set and the second set is the set of new entries.

Here is a demo based on a simplified version of your set-up:

```
declare
  nt table_achat;
begin
  nt := table_achat(achat(1 , 5),achat(2 , 3));
  dbms_output.put_line(nt.count());

  nt := nt multiset union table_achat(achat(3 , 44));
  dbms_output.put_line(nt.count());
end;
/
```

---

Given a table T42 with a column COL_NT which is a nested table of your `table_achat` type you could insert a new entry in the nested table like this:

```
insert into the 
(select col_nt from t42 where id = 1) 
values (achat(3,44));
```

Comment: Yes it's very useful !
I want to do same this but in a nested table who exist in an entry of table_client ..

Answer (score 0):

irrelevant from the question, which i couldn't and didn't try to understand, you can not combine `insert` + `select` + `values` statements as you did before. Perhaps you may prefer among below ones :

```
insert into the -- if table has one string column
(select ta from table_client where username=user);

OR

insert into the -- if table has two numeric columns
values (3,44);
```

Comment: no you are not right !!!
what I say before your edit work correctly !!!